# get id of HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am passing an HTMLDivElement in function as follows

```
var tableHTML = "...
<li name="Item2" onclick="onCombToPie2D(\'' + id + '\');" >Pie 2D</li>
....";

$('#graphsDiv').append(tableHTML);
```

I was able to access this element in the function as follows

```
function onCombToPie2D(element) {

    alert($('#element'));


}
```

but now i cannot access the id of this element. I have tried the following so far

```
alert($('#element').attr('id')); //undefined
alert($('#element').prop('id')); //undefined
alert(element.id); //undefined
```

In my viewsource the div is present (which is a kendo chart)

```
<div id="chartmd2467rt6" data-role="chart" class="k-chart" style="position: relative; touch-action: none;"> ... </div>
```

Comment: try `alert($('#element').length)`, if 0 then element is not exist, if 1 then try `alert($('#element').prop('outerHTML'));` to see if element is correct
... but `$('#element')` id attribute of course is "element"

Comment: just curious what the script is doing, your `onCombToPie2d` parameter did not really use in the function, what you actually try to do here? can you put ur `li` with an `id` as the same as`name`?

Comment: if `tableHTML` have multiple lines then you have to use `back-ticks` rather than starting and closing double bracket because it will give you error right now in your console.

Comment: thanks taufiq guess it is taking wrong element length = 0...however the element is present <div id ="chartmd2467rt6">..how do i pass its id to another function (please note i need to preserve this id, then destroy the object, recreate it and then use this id to access element)

Comment: @Samra you need to post full code

Comment: Se0ng11 i have a table with a kendochart in each td. on a certain action i destroy this table and create a table with just one chart/td. now from here users can go back to the previous state so i need to preserve the id of that single div/chart which initiated the process and do something with it. I am able to re-create all charts and tds again but this div element is giving me troubles

Comment: @Alive to Die ..i am adding more code

Comment: Is `element` not already the id? Try `console.log(element)`.

Comment: yay i found a way :) instead of passing element i passed the id only..posting answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of passing HTMLDivElement i passed its id to the function

```
<li name="Item2" onclick="onCombToPie2D(\'' + id.id + '\');" >Pie 2D</li>
```

Now in the function

```
function onCombToPie2D(element) {

    alert('#' + element);

}
```

this returned me the correct element

Comment: I am grateful to help if possible positively evaluate my response to help new users. I'm available.

Comment: here id is an HTMLDivElement object you have passed 'chartmd2467rt6' in the function which is id.id in my case. I have essentially done the same thing the only difference is using variable instead of hard coded id so i have voted for your answer

Answer (score 4):

try this sample:

```js
    function onCombToPie2D(idElemento) {

       alert($('#'+idElemento).attr('id'));

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li name="Item2" onclick="onCombToPie2D('chartmd2467rt6');" >Pie 2D</li>
</ul>
<div id="chartmd2467rt6" data-role="chart" class="k-chart" style="position: relative; touch-action: none;"> ... </div>
```

Comment: It's `undefined`. check before posting an answer

Comment: Check that it is putting the wrong id in the jquery selector `$('#element').attr('id')` and not `$('#'+element).attr('id')` with the correct element id

Comment: If `$('#'+element).attr('id')` gives the id doesn't that imply `element` already is the id?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with `data-attribute` rather than passing data as parameter.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li name="Item2" data-id="chartmd2467rt6" >Pie 2D</li>
  <li name="Item2" data-id="chartmd2467ry0" >Line 2D</li>
</ul>
<div id="chartmd2467rt6" data-role="chart" class="k-chart" style="position: relative; touch-action: none;"> ... </div>
```

Hope this will help you.